# Daylight Screen

Tags: screen

I have coded a graphical user interface (Qt) for monitoring a GPS and IMU connected to my Pi 3. The problem I have is that I haven't been able to find a decent daylight screen for the Pi.

The better option I have found is the Papirus `https://www.pi-supply.com/product/papirus-epaper-eink-screen-hat-for-raspberry-pi/`. However I cannot display nice graphics on it. I also have tried screens like the waveshare touch `http://www.waveshare.com/3.2inch-rpi-lcd-b.htm` however these can barely be seen with daylight.

Does anyone know about a good daylight readable screen smaller than 10 inch ?

---

Edit: I found this one: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1336174-REG/smallhd_mon_focus_5_touch_screen.html. It has 800 nits which should be enough to be used outdoors. However, it is engineered with photography/video recording in mind so it is pretty expensive due to some features that I won't be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking an answer for the same problem. Guess the only solution is to buy over 800 cd/m2 screen. i've found this https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/High-quality-5-inch-800x480-sunlight_60120693732.html its 600 cd/m2 as a inexpensive solution but dont know if it will do the trick. Please keep the post updated.

Comment: Nice. These are super cheap! Not sure if 600 nits will be enough. I'll buy one and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the low-tech approach of buying or building a sun visor (out of cardboard or similar material that fits around the screen, something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001IMJB86):

[image: sun visor]

or this [one](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?A=details&O=&Q=&ap=y&c3api=1876%2C%7Bcreative%7D%2C%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=Cj0KEQjw1ufKBRDYrqLzrY3dy88BEiQAPI_r4dYNGSTsUJeEEs-5QX-fyfO85ovkprK9ZRcsfKmHJoAaAhgG8P8HAQ&is=REG&m=Y&sku=1025575) which is designed for a 7in. screen:

[image]

Comment: Not a bad solution. However, I need to be able to see the screen from about 3 meters away, so the second picture is not valid. Further, I need a robust solution and the setup on the first picture will fail when the sun is a bit low.